# SQL partition by query optimization

Tags: postgresql

I have below prices table and I want to obtain last_30_days price array and last_year_price from it. As shown below

```
CREATE TABLE prices
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  "time" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  close double precision NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT prices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, "time")
)



select id,time,first_value(close) over (partition by id order by time range between '1 year' preceding and CURRENT ROW) as prev_year_close,
array_agg(p.close) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as prices_30
from prices p
```

However I want to place a where clause on the prices table to get last_30_days price array and last_year_price for some specific rows. **Eg. where time >= '1 week' interval  (so I run this query only for last 1 week values as opposed to the entire table)**

But a where clause pre-filtering the rows and then window partition only runs on that conditioned rows which results in wrong results. it is giving result like

```
time, id, last_30_days
-1day, X, [A,B,C,D,E, F,G]
-2day, X, [A,B,C,D,E,F]
-3day, X, [A,B,C,D,E]
-4day, X, [A,B,C,D] 
-5day, X, [A,B,C]
-6day, X, [A,B]
-7day, X, [A]
```

How do I fix this so that partition over window always takes 30 values irrespective of where condition? Without having to run the query always on the entire table and then selecting a subset of rows with where clause. My prices table is huge and running it on entire table is very expensive.

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TABLE prices
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  "time" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  close double precision NOT NULL,
  prev_30 double precision[],
  prev_year double precision, 
  CONSTRAINT prices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, "time")
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (select id, time,
             first_value(close) over (partition by id order by time range between '1 year' preceding and CURRENT ROW) as prev_year_close,
             array_agg(p.close) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time ROWS BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as prices_30 I
      from prices p
      WHERE time >= current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 year 1 week') AS q
WHERE time >= current_timestamp - INTERVAL '1 week' ;
```

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz Albe this is what i did also but explain suggests that the query goes over the entire prices table and not just the prices table that are within 1 week. The where is executed after the window functions had been run on the entire table. This is what I understand from the EXPLAIN because it takes a lot of time..

Comment: Of course it has to scan more than one week - where else should the information for the window function come from?

Comment: So there is no avoiding the entire table scan ?? Could it not just look at past 30 rows or past 1 year data from the rows requested in the results? Essentially my price table is a historic price series and I want to use this select for only recent week. It is too expense like this. Can we not restructure the select to be faster?

Comment: Sure, you can add a `WHERE` condition to the inner query that excludes rows older than a year anf a week.

Comment: WHERE in inner query will restrict the returned rows and window function may not get all results that the window wants. And return result like i show in the question already. Look at my edit schema. my table has a price series and i add latest price point everyday. After which i make an update to fill prev_30 and prev_year WHERE prev_30 and prev_year is null. Putting a WHERE in inner query will only return null entries and Window function will not get all the 30 rows previous to the null row. And hence not give me apt result.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show what I mean. Values older than a year and a week won't influence the result of the window function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It wasn't the exact solution but quite closed to what worked. Thanks for sparking the idea.